# How can one use Nvidia RTX IO on Linux to allow the GPU to directly access the storage (SSD) with only a slight CPU overhead?

Tags: nvidia, io, storage, gpu

I saw in the [2020-09-01 Official Launch Event for the NVIDIA GeForce RTX 30 Series](https://youtu.be/E98hC9e__Xs?t=1436) that the RTX IO in the [Nvidia GeForce RTX 30 Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_30_series) allows the GPU to directly access the storage (SSD) with only a slight CPU overhead when using Microsoft DirectStorage (see screenshot below). How can one use RTX IO on Linux?

[image]

Comment: "Question to Radio Eriwan: In principle, yes". If Nvidia makes the RTX IO specifications public, and if someone sits down and implements those in `nouveau`, and if someone sits down and implements an equivalent to DirectStorage in the Linux kernel, than it's possible. But that's three big "ifs". At least following the announcements, it's unlikely Nvidia will implement them in the `nvidia` driver.

Comment: @dirkt thanks, fair enough, rephrased

Comment: And with the rephrasing, the answer is obviously "currently, you can't". AFAIK you can't even use it on Windows yet.